# How do I restfully return images using laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a server set up to serve web pages on different domains (specifically a mobile device or localhost:9000 where laravel is serving on localhost:8000).  I'm trying to return image requests on these pages to my laravel server but I'm running into problems.  From a forum post, I thought that setting headers on a request would do the trick but, when I navigate to /api/v1/images/default.jpg, no default cat image is shown.  Instead, I get a box with no image.

Now, the image is in my public folder so if I browse to /public/images/default.jpg I do see my cat image, but I'd rather serve images within my /api/v1/... route.

```
Route::get('images/{imageName}', function($imageName){
    $img = 'public/images/' . $imageName;
    // return $img;
    echo $img . "\n\n";
    if(File::exists($img)) {
        // return "true";
        // return Response::make($img, 200, array('content-type' => 'image/jpg'));
        // return Response::download($img, $imageName);
        // Set headers
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$imageName."\"");
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        //stream the file out
        readfile($img);
        exit;
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
    return $img;
    // return File::exists($img);
    // return File::isFile('/images/' . $imageName);
    // return $imageName;
    // if(File::isFile('images/' + $imageName)){
    //  return Response::make('images/' + $imageName, 200, array('content-type' => 'image/jpg'));
    // }
});
```

Comment: Check this library http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Response::stream` method to do it:

```
Route::get('/image', function () {

      return Response::stream(function () {

              $filename = '/path/to/your/image.jpg';

              readfile($filename);

      }, 200, ['content-type' => 'image/jpeg']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stream your image from a ftp server ($imageName is the parameter)

```
    $server   = \Config::get('ftpconfig.server');
    $usuario  = \Config::get('ftpconfig.user');
    $password = \Config::get('ftpconfig.password');
    $path = \Config::get('ftpconfig.path');

    $file_location = "ftp://$usuario:".urlencode($password)."@".$server.$path.$imageName;

    $headers = [
        "Content-Type" => "image/jpeg",
        "Content-Length" => filesize($file_location),
        "Content-disposition" => "inline; filename=\"" . basename($file_location) . "\"",
    ];

    return \Response::stream(function () use ($file_location){

        readfile($file_location);
    }, 200, $headers)
```

Answer (score -2):

@Andrew Allbright,

If your images are located inside the laravel app directory then you can use

```
$img = app_path().'/api/v1/images/' . $imageName;
```

For image manipulation you can try Intervention

Comment: It's within my public folder and, even if my public folder is within my app folder, return app_path() . '/public/images/' . $imageName; only returns the path not the image.  I'm not trying to do image manipulation, just serve the image.

Comment: @Andrew Allbright, you could use $image = File::get(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE); and then return Response::make($image, 200, ['content-type' => 'image/jpg']);

Comment: Doesn't work either, for some reason...  Ah I give up, I'll just maintain a separate variable in my client-side code that points to the public folder to get images.  It'll make my client-side code more complicated but serving images as a response seems to elude me.  Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: It should be storage_path().'/app/public/images/....';